# Custom ResourceDictionary on WinRT either works at runtime or designtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I used the idea from [dev hedgehog about using a ResourceDictionary only in design mode](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23287.trick-to-use-a-resourcedictionary-only-when-in-design-mode.aspx) and tried to apply it to a WinRT app. But unfortunately it either does not work at design time or at runtime.

If the Source property is a `string` it does not work in design mode and Visual Studio shows the error message 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'.

If the Source is of type `URI` it works in design mode but I get an exception at runtime: 'Failed to assign to property Source'.

Is it possible to make it work in both cases?

```
public class DesignTimeResouceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
   // works at run-time
   public new string Source {
      get {
         return base.Source.ToString();
      }
      set {
         if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            base.Source = new Uri(value);
      }
   }

   // works at design time
   public new Uri Source {
      get {
         return base.Source;
      }
      set {
         if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            base.Source = value;
      }
   }
}
```

The usage in App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <local:DesignTimeResourceDictionary Source="OnlyForDesignTime.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResouceDictionary>
```

Comment: So I don't know if it's a good idea to have both properties have the same name. Maybe "DesignSource" and "Source"? If this is the case then you shouldn't need "new" on the string property.

Comment: Upon further consideration I wonder if Source has a private dependency property that isn't being triggered at runtime.